# What's the correct behaviour of SVG "defs" tag in CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, svg, w3c

When one write this SVG code, with embedded CSS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <style>
        defs rect
        {
            fill:           blue;
        }
    </style>
    <defs>
        <rect id="rectangle" x="5" y="10" width="3" height="3"/>
    </defs>

    <rect x="5" y="5" width="3" height="3"/>
    <use xlink:href="#rectangle"/>
</svg>
```

Then, **Chrome does** apply the "fill:blue" rule to the second rect through the use tag (so first rect is black, second is blue), whereas **firefox does not** apply the rule (both rects remain black).

Is that a firebug? Is there something I don't get? Or does the standard say "defs tag should block CSS selectors"?

Comment: Using `defs` as a selector is like using `title` in HTML. You normally wouldn't do that since `defs` is just a logical container, not a block you would normally style. If it's a bug, it's surely an avoidable one. Elements in `defs` are only useful with an `id` since they need to be referred elsewhere to be useful, so you can always refer to such an element using its id.

Comment: @helderarocha Okay for #id and .class, but what if I want to apply the rule according to node's name, like here?
Well, I'll consider that as bug so I'll report it to firebug.

Comment: if you use just id or inline attribut file , it works , the bug is morelike : why should it fill <defs> too ?  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uoqwr/

Comment: I don't get why `defs rect` should `fill` the defs? It fills all rects inside the defs. If I have a rect outside and don't want it to be filled, I could use `defs rect`.
Or did you mean "fill" another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It's actually a bug from Firefox.**

Rules apply to the `defs rect` elements, but they don't apply when the `use` tag clones the `defs rect`.
Replacing the `defs` with a `g` tag shows that the `defs rect` is filled; but the rules are not applied to the "-generated clone".

**Correct behavior is Chrome's one**, filling the use-generated clone; use-cloned version of the `defs rect` is wrongly not filled by firefox.

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=997362#c4 for more explanations.