# Do browsers render all SVGs twice?

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, svg

This is a pretty standard way of inlining SVGs to be used later. It was made popular by Chris Coyier of CSS-tricks in [Icon System with SVG Sprites](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/) and presumably thousands of developers have ditched icon fonts in favor of SVGs.

```css
.icon {
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;" hidden>
  <defs>
    <g id="circle">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
      </svg>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="#circle" />
</svg>
```

The `<svg>` with the `<defs>` is made hidden (twice just to be sure!), even though if `<defs>` has any semantics, browsers should *not* render anything inside `svg/defs`.

But are those SVGs really hidden? Let's add a rule for the `<g>` element in the `<defs`>, which is inside a *hidden* `<svg>` with **`display: none`**. Double hide.

```css
.icon {
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}

defs g {
   outline: 30px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;" hidden>
  <defs>
    <g id="circle">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
      </svg>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="#circle" />
</svg>
```

Say what? What's the deal with those four green fellas? Why is that `g` rendered? Firefox and IE don't show any green outline.

Does this show that wherever you `<use>` SVGs, Chrome renders them twice?

Oh, but it's not just Chrome. If you add a fill to that `g`, IE11 will render it too:

[image]

Comment: @RobertLongson: IE renders the `fill` in a defs/g too.

Comment: Filed [issue with Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509253). @Robert: congrats, Firefox has the best rendering :)

Comment: To me it looks like Chrome is doing the rendering as one should expect; the error seems to be with Firefox, instead. You style the `<g id="circle">` and when you use it, it gets rendered. This assumption is backed by a similar [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23121891/4235784) on SO. To my surprise this links to [bug 997362](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=997362) on bugzilla which has comments by @RobertLongson stating Firefox's `<use>` to be erroneous. That makes me wonder. Did I miss something?

Comment: Ahh, yes I get what's happening now. Firefox has the worst rendering of `<use>` elements :-( No, you didn't miss anything @altocumulus It's the `<use>` that's rendering, not the `<defs>` directly.

Comment: In fact, IE may be even closest to the truth, since `outline` is not a valid attribute in SVGs. Hence, you got the circle rendered in blue using `fill` while `outline` is disregarded.

Comment: Score one for IE, 1/2 for Chrome and 0 for Firefox.